"idxmax() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" error after upgrading Azure-Kusto-Data and Azure-Kusto-Ingest to > 3.0.0
Goal: Upgrade current Azure-kusto-data and Azure-kusto-ingest from 2.0.0 to >= 3.0.0
Current 2.0.0 version does not cause any issue when trying to use Panda's idxmax() function but after the upgrade I'm encountering "idxmax() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" error.
Here's the method where the error occurs:
def dedupe_telemetry_by_max(df: pd.DataFrame,
                     timestamp_column='TimeStamp',
                     dedupe_column='DataPoint',
                     value_column='Value',
                     how='max'):
    if len(df) == 0:
        return df

    idx = df.groupby([timestamp_column, dedupe_column])[value_column].idxmax()
    return df.loc[idx, :]

Here's a portion of data from df.groupby([timestamp_column, dedupe_column])[value_column] before using idxmax()
((Timestamp('2024-08-27 21:32:54.632000+0000', tz='UTC'), 'device0.Amps.ChannalA'), 0    16.0
1    16.0
Name: Value, dtype: Float64)
((Timestamp('2024-08-27 21:32:54.632000+0000', tz='UTC'), 'device1.Amps.ChannalA'), 35361    119.0
35362    119.0
Name: Value, dtype: Float64)
((Timestamp('2024-08-27 21:32:54.632000+0000', tz='UTC'), 'device1.Amps.ChannalC'), 35360    122.0
35363    122.0
Name: Value, dtype: Float64)
((Timestamp('2024-08-27 21:32:54.632000+0000', tz='UTC'), 'device2.Amps.ChannalA'), 41393    113.0
41396    113.0
Name: Value, dtype: Float64)
((Timestamp('2024-08-27 21:32:54.632000+0000', tz='UTC'), 'device2.Amps.ChannalB'), 41394    109.0
41397    109.0
Name: Value, dtype: Float64)

Here's the tracelogs:
File "c:\infra\proj\infra\periodic_service.py", line 81, in run
    self.periodic_fn()
  File "c:\infra\proj\infra\metrics\perf_metric.py", line 72, in wrapper
    return _perf_metric(
  File "c:\infra\proj\infra\metrics\perf_metric.py", line 116, in _perf_metric
    raise e
  File "c:\infra\proj\infra\metrics\perf_metric.py", line 103, in _perf_metric
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ipd\ipd\ipd_multi.py", line 58, in run_cycle
    agent.run()
  File "c:\infra\proj\infra\metrics\perf_metric.py", line 135, in wrapper
    return _perf_metric(f, timer, dimensions, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\infra\proj\infra\metrics\perf_metric.py", line 116, in _perf_metric
    raise e
  File "c:\infra\proj\infra\metrics\perf_metric.py", line 103, in _perf_metric
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\ipd\ipd\dc_agent.py", line 136, in run
    return self.poll()
  File "c:\ipd\ipd\dc_agent.py", line 147, in poll
    return self.ingestion.poll_once(self._on_telemetry_ingested)
  File "c:\ipd\ipd\ingestion\telemetry_ingestor.py", line 103, in poll_once
    (df, st, et) = self.now_dataframe()
  File "c:\ipd\ipd\ingestion\telemetry_ingestor.py", line 49, in now_dataframe
    return self.dataframe_ending(end_time)
  File "c:\infra\proj\infra\metrics\perf_metric.py", line 135, in wrapper
    return _perf_metric(f, timer, dimensions, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\infra\proj\infra\metrics\perf_metric.py", line 116, in _perf_metric
    raise e
  File "c:\infra\proj\infra\metrics\perf_metric.py", line 103, in _perf_metric
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\infra\proj\infra\retry.py", line 58, in wrapper
    return perf_metric(logging_name)(f)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\infra\proj\infra\metrics\perf_metric.py", line 135, in wrapper
    return _perf_metric(f, timer, dimensions, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\infra\proj\infra\metrics\perf_metric.py", line 116, in _perf_metric
    raise e
  File "c:\infra\proj\infra\metrics\perf_metric.py", line 103, in _perf_metric
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\ipd\ipd\ingestion\telemetry_ingestor.py", line 73, in dataframe_ending
    return self._dataframe_ending(end_dt, TELEMETRY_WINDOW_SIZE_TIMEDELTA)
  File "c:\ipd\ipd\ingestion\telemetry_ingestor.py", line 82, in _dataframe_ending
    df = self.telemetry_reader.read_dc_telemetry(self.datacenter_code, start_dt, end_dt)
  File "c:\ipd\ipd\dataproviders\telemetry\telemetry_reader\smartdc_telemetry_reader.py", line 119, in read_dc_telemetry
    telemetry_df = self._transform_telemetry_schema(telemetry_df, start_dt, end_dt, dc_code)
  File "c:\ipd\ipd\dataproviders\telemetry\telemetry_reader\smartdc_telemetry_reader.py", line 193, in _transform_telemetry_schema
    df = dedupe_telemetry_by_max(df,
  File "c:\infra\proj\infra\data_transformation.py", line 378, in dedupe_telemetry_by_max
    idx = df.groupby([timestamp_column, dedupe_column])[value_column].idxmax()
  File "c:\ipd\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 817, in wrapper
    return self._python_apply_general(curried, self._obj_with_exclusions)
  File "c:\ipd\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 928, in _python_apply_general
    keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, data, self.axis)
  File "c:\ipd\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py", line 237, in apply
    res = f(group)
  File "c:\ipd\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 806, in curried
    return f(x, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\ipd\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2145, in idxmax
    i = nanops.nanargmax(self._values, skipna=skipna)
  File "c:\ipd\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 71, in _f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\ipd\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 1027, in nanargmax
    result = values.argmax(axis)
TypeError: argmax() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Here's the current packages being used:
azure-cli>=2.50.0
azure-core
azure-data-tables==12.4.0
azure-identity==1.16.1
azure-keyvault==1.1.0
azure-kusto-data==2.0.0
azure-kusto-ingest==2.0.0
azure-storage-blob==12.13.1
azure-storage-file-datalake==12.2.0
azure-storage-queue==12.4.0
azure-cosmosdb-table==1.0.6
azure-keyvault-secrets
cachetools==4.2.1
certifi==2023.7.22
coverage==6.4.2
cryptography==42.0.*
h5py==3.1.0
jinja2==3.*
Keras==2.13.*
Keras-Preprocessing
lightgbm==3.3.2
matplotlib==3.3.3
msal==1.*
numpy==1.23.5
opencensus-context==0.1.2
opencensus-ext-azure==1.0.5
pandas==1.2.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
protobuf
pyarrow==14.0.1
pyOpenSSL
PyJWT==2.4.0
PySocks==1.7.1
python-docx==0.8.11
readerwriterlock==1.0.8
scikit-learn==1.1.3
scikit-image==0.18.0
scipy==1.10.*
seaborn==0.11.0
simplejson==3.17.2
statsd==3.3.0
tensorboard==2.13.*
tensorboard-plugin-wit
tensorflow==2.13.*
tensorflow-estimator==2.13.*
tsfresh==0.17.0
statsmodels==0.12.1
tornado==6.4.*

I've compared the data in df.groupby([timestamp_column, dedupe_column])[value_column] when running version 2.0.0 to >= 3.0.0 and they look the same. So I didn't see any issue with the input.

Upgrade your pandas to latest version and try pip install --upgrade pandas
